Entity Framework reverse-engineer only select schema
I have a project to try and work with an existing database we have.  It's a new project and I was going to use EF Core 8.0 to work with the database.
I know how to scaffold from an existing database, but the database for this project has around 100+ tables and I don't need to deal with those tables. I only need to deal with around 20 of them for my task.  And even those tables, there's only a handful of columns that I care about.
Is there a better way of setting all of this up without scaffolding a bunch of schema I don't care about?
Also, I know about the POCO tool, but that doesn't work for me, since we can't really be buying licenses to software right now.

This is all in the documentation, did you even look? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold

I suspect there's a misunderstanding about what EF and ORMs in general are. Never mind "POCO Tool" and licenses - the EF CLI tools are open source. ORMs aren't database drivers and don't represent every table in the database. They represent application entities and map them to database tables, so developers can work as if they were working with in-memory objects instead of tables and rows. You don't have to use any tool to create a C# class and map it, although the built-in CLI tools can save some time. If your classes follow EF conventions, you won't need a lot of configuration either

Just use EF Core Power Tools

Apart from using -t to specify only the tables you want, you can use -d to generate attributes instead of model configuration. With just 20 auto-generated classes with properties, it's then very easy to just delete the properties you don't want. As for better way of setting all of this up by the time you can generate just 20 classes, the only way to improve is to .... simply write the classes yourself. It won't take more code than typing the property names explicitly

And yes, EF Core Power Tools. This will allow you to just pick the tables and columns from a list. With just 20 tables that's not a lot of work. Template customization and the saved config file means it's a lot easier to reproduce the steps too, add the config file to GIT  and create classes just the way you like them

I did read the documentation.  I was hoping to avoid a very, very long string of -t to solve my problem.

Also, if I don't need to use power tools at all, that'd be great!  But almost all demos and tutorials online only show how to use power tools.  They don't show the actual set up and mapping that I'd need to do.  Is that anywhere?  That would, honestly, solve my problem outright.

I was finally able to understand Entity Framework well enough to get the answer for this.
The main point I needed was accessing the DBContext that's created for Entity Framework, and then creating the configurations for each model object I plan on working with.  Each configuration will need their own table and field definitions, and I only need to tie the relevant table fields to the columns with these config files.  I have a demo of one below, to show others what I was missing, since there's no straight-forward documentation out there about this.
namespace Test.TestContextMapping
{
  public class TestDBContext : DBContext
  {
    public TestDBContext () {}
    public TestDBContext (DbContextOptions<TestDBContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
  public DbSet<Table1> TableData { get; set; }
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    new TableConfig().Configuration(modelBuilder.Entity<Table1>());
  }
  public class TableConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Table1>
  {
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Table1> entity)
    {
      // This is where you specify database schema that this model configuration ties to
      entity.ToTable("table");
      // This is where you specify any primary keys
      entity.HasKey(e => e.ID);
      // Below are the definitions of what model fields tie to what schema fields
      entity.Property(e => e.ID)
        .HasColumnName("id")
        .HasColumnType("int")
        .IsRequired();
      entity.Property(e => e.Name)
        .HasColumnName("tableName")
        .IsRequired();
    }
  }
  public class Table1
  {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!
  }
}

Here, you can see that I'm linking a model (Table1) to a database table (table), where the model ID ties to id and the model Name ties to tableName.  With this, it's easy to configure the Entity Framework to conform to your business and database needs without having to scaffold a lot of tables and schema that you don't need.
